# How to adjust characters in JAVA

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am trying make the hashtags to adjust to my text. For example, if I write "message hello, how are you?" I want it to print with capital letters and that the hashtags adjust themselves depending on how many characters I print. Do you have any suggestions on what I can use to make this happen?

```
public void addMessage() {
    System.out.println("Write message followed by a text: ");
    String message = readString();
    System.out.println("############################################################");
    System.out.println("#                                                          #");
    System.out.println("#" + message.substring(7).toUpperCase() + "                 #");
    System.out.println("#                                                    #");
    System.out.println("############################################################");
}
```

Comment: For your information, the character "#" is called "hash", not "hashtag".

Comment: Use [`String#lenght()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--) on `message.substring(7)` and some basic math to calculate the number of hashes you want to print.

Comment: You could use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Comment: And you should check that `message` has at least 7 characters before invoking `substring(7)`.

Comment: Remember to add example input and output, I see there are multiple interpretations of what you are after in the answers provided.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is calculate length of your string and output hashs specified amount of times.

The code below should be helpful.

```
String hashs(int len) {
    return new String(new char[len]).replace("\0", "#");
}
int textLen = message.length();
System.out.println(hashs(len + 2));
System.out.println("#" + message.toUpperCase() + "#");
System.out.println(hashs(len + 2));
```

Comment: Nice way to generate a String of a certain length with the same characters :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public void addMessage() {
    System.out.println("Write message followed by a text: ");
    String message = readString();

    System.out.println(createHashes(input.length() + 2));
    System.out.println("#" + createSpaces(input.length()) + "#");
    System.out.println("#" + input.toUpperCase() + "#");
    System.out.println("#" + createSpaces(input.length()) + "#");
    System.out.println(createHashes(input.length() + 2));
}

private String createHashes(final Integer numberOfHashes) {
    return new String(new char[numberOfHashes]).replace("\0", "#");
}

private String createSpaces(final Integer numberOfSpaces) {
    return new String(new char[numberOfSpaces]).replace("\0", " ");
}
```

Example input/output:

input: Hey, you!

output:

```
###########
#         #
#HEY, YOU!#
#         #
###########
```

input: How you doin'?

output:

```
################
#              #
#HOW YOU DOIN'?#
#              #
################
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

```
    String[] strings  = {"one", "two", "three"};
    for(String item: strings){
        System.out.printf("#%20s      #\n", item.toUpperCase());
    }
```

That way the string print will always have the same width. For this example the output is:

```
#                 ONE     #
#                 TWO     #
#               THREE     #
```